# Zoho subscription API to Wordpress

Tags: api

Please help me to integrate ZOHO subscription api to Wordpress without using any plugins. 
Project process would be: 
1. Wordpress: The user can choose product and it's add on in the form options. I need to retrieve the data of the Zoho products
2. After submission: redirect to the specific zoho page that was selected

Comment: What **exactly** is your problem? Please read [ask], and edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you believe that there won't be frequent changes to the plans and
>   addons, you can hard code the HTML pages displaying the plans and
>   addons for your customer to select.

Once the customer selects the plans and addons, you can use the Plan Specific URL in to embed the Zoho Subscriptions' checkout page.

```
https://subscriptions.zoho.com/subscribe/{{encryptedID}}/{{plan_code}}
```

Note that this encryptedID will be same for all the plans in an organization.

If you want to add addons to this page, you can simply append them as parameters.

```
https://subscriptions.zoho.com/subscribe/3b884751f87f05e584c3952b6388e7f96a2bba0f6b0532177e00f0ba8db832fc/mnthly-essential?addon_code[0]=wiki&addon_quantity[0]=2&addon_code[1]=chat&addon_quantity[1]=1
```

You can refer [this Help Documentation](https://www.zoho.com/subscriptions/help/hp-types.html#plan-specific-urls) for a detailed explanation.

> Or, if you want to use the API for displaying the plans or if you have
>   custom requirements which cannot be achieved using Plan Specific URLs,
>   follow the below-mentioned steps.

You can use the Plan List API of Zoho Subscriptions to list the plans for your customer to select.

```
$headers = array('X-com-zoho-subscriptions-organizationid' => $organization_id , 'Authorization' => 'Zoho-authtoken '.$authtoken);

wp_remote_get("https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/plans", array('headers' => $headers));
```

Once the customer selects the plan, you can use the Addon List API with `plan_code` as a parameter to get all the addons associated with the selected plan.

```
wp_remote_get("https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/addons?plan_code=".$code, array('headers' => $headers));
```

Once you collect all the order details, you can use Hosted Page API for creating a subscription to retrieve the URL to be embedded in your checkout page to collect the customer information and payment information.

````
$headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'X-com-zoho-subscriptions-organizationid' => $organization_id , 'Authorization': 'Zoho-authtoken '.$authtoken);

$body = array('plan' => array('plan_code' => 'basic-monthly',  'price' => 400, 'quantity' => 1 ), 'addons' => array(...) );

wp_remote_post("https://subscriptions.zoho.com/api/v1/hostedpages/newsubscription", array('headers' => $headers, 'body' => $body));


```Request Example in JSON
    {
       "plan": {
        "plan_code": "basic-monthly",
        "price": 400,
        "quantity": 1
      },
      "addons": [
          {
            "addon_code": "Email-basic",
            "price": 50,
            "quantity": 5
          }
      ]
    }
````

You can also pass the customer details to this API if you want to collect only the payment information using Zoho Subscriptions' checkout page.

You can also refer the [API documentation](https://www.zoho.com/subscriptions/api/v1/) of Zoho Subscriptions or write to us at support[at]zohosubscriptions[dot]com.